# Is there any difference between testing Android app bundle and APK

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to publish my app in Android app bundle(.aab) format to Google play but I don't want to extract apks from Android app bundle when I am testing locally as it is somewhat difficult compared to sideload single apk.

So Is there any difference between testing total apk and Split apks which can be extracted from Android app bundle

Should I be worried if I deploy my Android app bundle directly to Google play after testing APK ?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue. There is no practical difference between apk and bundle. I have done it multiple times without any issues.

But for mimicking the real play store update, you can first upload the bundle for Alpha testing in google play console and add your email as alpha tester. Then you should enroll for alpha testing from the given url after uploading the bundle. After few hours, your should get the update in your phone.